# Почему слетела кодировка в sql, и как всё исправить?

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Есть локальный проект на OpenServer, база данных в кодировке utf8_general_ci с тремя полями и скрипт вывода всего этого на страничку:

[image: Сама таблица]

```
<?php
  
  $connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "organiser");
  mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysqli_query($connect, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
  mysqli_query($connect, "SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8';");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `notes`";
  $notes_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, $query));
  

?>
```

При выводе текста на страницу там вот такая вот красота:

[image: Вопросики]

Конфиг Open Server:

1. Apache 2.4
2. PHP 5.5
3. MySQL 5.6

Пробовал менять сравнение у столбцов таблицы - ноль эффекта.
Добавление к коду `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8', true);` результата не дало.

Comment: второй строкой: mysqli_set_charset($connect ,"utf8"); Остальные лишние

Comment: Не дает никакого результата(

Comment: а у самой таблицы какое сравнение? в заголовке

Comment: а если хидер правильно написать? header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сбросьте Open Server настройка и заполните все значения кнопка
должна работать